# RHEL 7: Add PATH variables globally

Tags: rhel, environment-variables, path

Under my profile and the .bashrc file. I have added several environment variables.
Example:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/app/hadoop-2.7.3
```

When I try to run any "hadoop" command I get command not found.

After executing this command "exec bash" I will be able then to run hadoop commands without issues.

The problem I am having that every time I log  in to the server I will need to run the exec command to be able to use hadoop, plus there are other users on the server that need to use the application.

How can I update the PATH globally so everyone can use hadoop and any other installed application?

Thank you

Comment: "command not found" means `PATH` is wrong, not `HADOOP_HOME`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file in `/etc/profile.d` called `hadoop.sh`.

Add these lines to the file:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/app/hadoop-2.7.3
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

`JAVA_HOME` also needs to be set in order for Hadoop to function which I've added above assuming you are using Java 1.8.0.

Make the file executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh
```

The `bin` directory for Hadoop will be prepended to everyone's path at login.

Comment: Need to fix `PATH` so it includes the original path and not *only* hadoop's bin!

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger I must have forgotten to copy the entirety when I did it on my test machine! That's a good catch.